# Why Cython compilation could fails (on C stage), while working well in Jupyter?

Tags: cython, cl

Here's the code that works perfectly fine in Jupyter %%cython cell:

```
ctypedef fused fused_type:
    long
    double

cdef fused_checker(fused_type i):
    if fused_type is long:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def test():
    return fused_checker(0)
```

But when I put it into .pyx file, compilation fails on C stage failing with error C2065 (unknown identifier)

#### update:

The problem was in `Cython.Compiler.Options.cimport_from_pyx = True` I used in my setup.py. Without it everything works fine. My fault I didn't notice it before. So it's time to file an issue...

Comment: It's most likely a different version of Cython being used in Jupyter (in which case you should work out what's more up to date...). If you're using the most recent version of Cython then this looks like it should be a bug report instead of a stack overflow question.

Comment: It works for me with up-to-date Cython. I was using GCC rather than MSVC though (but "unknown identifier" seems like an error they should both have)

Comment: I figured out what I was missing and edited original question